# How to call onAppear on NavigationView when getting back from child view?

Tags: swiftui

How do I make `NavigationView` call `onAppear()`(or any other functions) whenever it appears, especially when I back out from its child view?

I linked 3 `NavigationView`s in this way: `TestView` -> `SecondView` -> `ThirdView`, and I put `onAppear()` function on `TestView` and `SecondView`.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var text:String = "This is page 1"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(text)

                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondView(),
                    label: { Text("go to page2") }
                )
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            text += " called+1 "
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State var text:String = "This is page 2"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(text)

                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ThirdView(),
                    label: { Text("go to page3") }
                )
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            text += " called+1 "
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is page 3")
    }
}
```

From the function name `onAppear()`, I thought it would be invoked every time the view appears. However, it turns out it will only be invoked once when I go deeper into a new view, but **NOT** invoked when I back out from its child view.

In other words, when the app launches, `TestView`'s `onAppear()` will be called. Then, when I click `go to page2`, `SecondView`'s `onAppear()` will be called. Then I click `go to page3`, and then I click the `back` button on the `ThirdView`, `SecondView`'s `onAppear()` will bot be invoked, even though the current view is `SecondView`. And it is the same when I click `back` on the `SecondView`, the `TestView`'s `onAppear()` is not invoked again.

How to call `onAppear()` when I click `Back`, or used other method to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this approach, moving the `TestView`, `.onAppear {..}` to
the `VStack{..}` as shown in the example code. Also there is no need
for the `SecondView` `NavigationView`. With these changes all `.onAppear {..}` work well for me.

Note that `NavigationView` is deprecated, use the `NavigationStack` instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var text:String = "This is page 1"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(text)
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), label: { Text("go to page2") })
            }
            .onAppear {
                text += " called+1 "
                print("\n------> TestView onAppear ")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State var text: String = "This is page 2"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(),label: { Text("go to page3") })
        }
        .onAppear {
            text += " called+1 "
            print("\n------> SecondView onAppear ")
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is page 3")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just have a single `NavigationView` and if you want multiple levels of navigation you have to set `.isDetail(false)` on the links or set `.navigationStyle(.stack)` on the navigation view.